# how can i get the current_link id?

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2.I want to get the id of current_link.Please help me to find the id of current_link.

public function checkUrl(){

```
        $current_link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        $current_link=ltrim($current_link, '/');

        $current_link=ltrim($current_link, 'cable');

        $current_link=ltrim($current_link, '/');

        $plink = DB::table('roles')->where('id',$current_link->id)->get();

        // print_r($plink);
        // die();

         $dlink= DB::table('my_roles')->where('role_id',$current_link->role_id)->get();


       if($plink!=$dlink){
             Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Error!! You dont have the permission to access this page'));
             return Redirect::action('Admin\DashboardController@index');
          }

    }
```

Comment: show your output..? is you get multiple ids in $dlink

Comment: i want to get the current_link id and current_link role_id

Comment: how can you get this $current_link->role_id ........?

Comment: What does the URI look like? Why not just capture the ID in your route?